# UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

i tried to define a UIBarButtonItem programatically. it showed up in the navBar as expected. but it didn´t call the action until i went to the IB and dragged an bar button item into the navigation controller object and assigned it with the didTapSearch action.

i thought it´s possible to define UIBarButtonItems programatically only, without any additional IB work. or is that only possible if the navigation controller and/or the view controller was created programatically as well?

or did i miss to set a delegate in my code again?

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBtn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(didTapSearch:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBtn;
```

Comment: do u cant able to call the didTapSearch function?

Comment: this link will also help you
http://cocoadevblog.com/uinavigationcontroller-customization-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

try this way instead
in the header, declare the barButtonItem

```
proximityButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                  initWithTitle:@"Nearby Locations"                                            
                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                  target:self 
                  action:@selector(addToProximity)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = proximityButton;
```

and you can take out the :(id)sender part of the action

Answer (score 0):

You could specific the `action:` method programatically as you have done with your `UIBarButtonItem`.

Implement **action** method in the class of object which you specified with `target:`.

```
-(void) didTapSearch:(id) sender
{
  UIBarButtonItem *searchBtn = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a color to it.

```
searchBtn.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```